# XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and prefix + xmlNamespace issue

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectnodes

I have the following string loaded to an XML document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>El cliente con los parámetros introducidos no existe./faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns:ClienteWSDo29Exception xmlns:ns="http://services.do29.imq.es">
               <Do29Exception xmlns="http://services.do29.imq.es" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax211="http://model.do29.imq.es/xsd" xmlns:ax213="http://dto.do29.imq.es/xsd" xmlns:ax29="http://exception.do29.imq.es/xsd" xsi:type="ax29:Do29Exception">
                  <ax29:classname>class es.imq.do29.dao.ClienteDaoImpl</ax29:classname>
                  <ax29:trace xsi:nil="true" />
                  <ax29:previous xsi:nil="true" /> 
                  <ax29:method>getCliente</ax29:method>
                  <ax29:id>1</ax29:id>
                  <ax29:message>El cliente con los parámetros introducidos no existe.</ax29:message>
               </Do29Exception>
            </ns:ClienteWSDo29Exception>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then following the case with namespaces in xml i tried:

```
XmlDocument xmldocu = new XmlDocument();
xmldocu.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldocu.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("ax29", "http://services.do29.imq.es");
XmlNode nodemsgx = xmldocu.SelectSingleNode("//message", namespaces);
XmlNode nodemsg = xmldocu.SelectSingleNode("//ax29:message", namespaces);
```

But nodemsgx and nodemsg are null :S Whats the correct way to do it?
I used //message becouse i want to get any node of that type not the specific path to this node...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ax29` prefix in the XML document is set to the `"http://exception.do29.imq.es/xsd"` namespace, not `"http://services.do29.imq.es"`.

Try this:

```
namespaces.AddNamespace("ax29", "http://exception.do29.imq.es/xsd");
XmlNode nodemsg = xmldocu.SelectSingleNode("//ax29:message", namespaces);
```

Comment: Thanks you nailed it...(with so many namespaces i was misleaded...)

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell for us since we don't know what resul contains, but I'm guessing it contains xmldocu?

Have you tried getting any other elements from the document?

does 
XmlNode nodemsg = xmldocu.SelectSingleNode("detail//ax29:message"); yield anything?