# XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode omit prefixes and namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, selectsinglenode, selectnodes

This question is a follow up of the answered question: 
[XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and prefix + xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411736/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-prefix-xmlnamespace-issue)

The problem is that its possible that in the future the namespaces prefixes of the xml received will be changed without warning, so we would like to know if there is any way of using SelectSingleNode but omitting the prefix of an element.

(We know we could remove all the prefixes of the incoming xml but it would require more steps....albeit we would consider it a valid answer if code is provided...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the prefix names change, as long as the namespace URIs do not change.

The prefix name you use in your code and the one in the XML document do not have to match, e.g.

```
namespaces.AddNamespace("foo", "http://exception.do29.imq.es/xsd");
XmlNode nodemsg = xmldocu.SelectSingleNode("//foo:message", namespaces);
```

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to omit it using * in the xpath, for example:

```
//*[local-name()='ElementName']
```

Based on the question [XPath select node with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536441/xpath-namespace-driving-me-crazy)

As an extra this tool was very useful to test different xpaths.... http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/